# PHP Notice: Undefined index, variable

Tags: php, mysql

tengo este error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: user in /home/clubbrit/public_html/socios/administrador/header.php on line 6
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: nombre in /home/clubbrit/public_html/socios/administrador/header.php on line 67
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cve_usuario in /home/clubbrit/public_html/socios/administrador/header.php on line 77
```

Este es el código que tengo en el header:

```
$usuario=$_SESSION['user']; 
$view->Sociousr=Sociousr::getUsuarioPorClave($usuario); 
foreach ($view->Sociousr as $Usuario):  
$nombre = $Usuario["username"];
$cve_usuario = $Usuario["cve_usuario"];
endforeach;
```

Comment: Primeramente no son errores, son advertencias (notice). La primera indica que en `$_SESSION` no hay nada que se llama `user`. Y las otras dos indican que estás usando las variables `nombre` y `cve_usuario` antes de declararlas, quizá tratas de usarla dentro de `$view->Sociousr=Sociousr::getUsuarioPorClave($usuario);`

Comment: Tu error principal es que no existe o no estás llamando bien el indice user del $_SESSION , tienes session_strat() en tu código ? veo que no lo colocaste en el ejemplo !

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pude resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta no trabajar con los datos de "user" si no tienes la seguridad de que este ya se haya pasado.

Usa una condición para ejecutar tu sentencia

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   $usuario=$_SESSION['user']; 
   $view->Sociousr=Sociousr::getUsuarioPorClave($usuario); 
   //.... continua con tu código
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo pude resolver